# Why my 2 account is log in at the same time?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I have 2 log in, one for admin table and the other one is for cashier table. So what is happening right now is whenever I log in either one of them then the other one is also log when I refresh it. Same goes when I log out when I click log out in admin then refresh the cashier the cashier is also log out. I dont 
know whats wrong in my codes.

P.S. The two table is in one database only. But I dont think its need 2 database for 2 log in.

This is the code index.php for admin_tbl

```
<?php 
/** *index.php **/ 
session_unset(); 
session_start();
require_once 'includes/database.php';
$error = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
 $uname = $_POST['username']; 
 $pword = $_POST['password'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_tbl WHERE uname='$uname' AND pword='$pword' LIMIT 1"; 
 $result = mysqli_query(connection(), $sql);
 $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); 
 if ($user)
 {
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id']; $_SESSION['name'] = $user['lastname'] . ', ' . $user['firstname']; 
 header("Location: user_maintenance.php");
 }
 else
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Account does not exist!")';
    echo '</script>';
 } 
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 {
    header("Location: user_maintenance.php");
    }

    ?>
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Log In</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body {

    background:url(images/jerica.jpg)fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'helvetica','Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: ;
    font-weight: 300;
        padding-top: 110px; 
        } 
    .navbar {
            background-color: #0A3D73;
            } 
    .navbar-brand { 
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 70px; 
    color: #fff !important;
    } 
    .footer { 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; 
    }
    .newtext{
        color: grey;
    }
    @media (max-width: 367px){ 
    .login-form {
        margin-top: 5px; 
        }
            }
        </style> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 well login-form" style="margin-top:40px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);"> <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <h1 class = "newtext"><center>Login</center></h1>
        <?php if ($error != ''): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <?= $error ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12"> <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> 
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="student" value="student"> 
        <div class="form-inline">
        <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login"> Log In</button>
        </form>
        </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

And this is the code of index.php for cashier_tbl

```
<?php 
/** *index.php **/ 
session_unset(); 
session_start();
require_once 'includes/database.php';
$error = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
 $uname = $_POST['username']; 
 $pword = $_POST['password'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cashier_tbl WHERE uname='$uname' AND pword='$pword' LIMIT 1"; 
 $result = mysqli_query(connection2(), $sql);
 $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); 
 if ($user)
 {
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id']; $_SESSION['name'] = $user['lastname'] . ', ' . $user['firstname'] . ' ' . $user['middlename']; 
 header("Location: order.php");
 }
 else
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Account does not exist!")';
    echo '</script>';
 } 
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 {
    header("Location: order.php");
    }

    ?>
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Log In</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body {

    background:url(images/jerica.jpg)fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'helvetica','Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: ;
    font-weight: 300;
        padding-top: 110px; 
        } 
    .navbar {
            background-color: #0A3D73;
            } 
    .navbar-brand { 
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 70px; 
    color: #fff !important;
    } 
    .footer { 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; 
    }
    .newtext{
        color: grey;
    }
    @media (max-width: 367px){ 
    .login-form {
        margin-top: 5px; 
        }
            }
        </style> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 well login-form" style="margin-top:40px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);"> <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <h1 class = "newtext"><center>Login</center></h1>
        <?php if ($error != ''): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <?= $error ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12"> <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> 
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required> 
        </div> 
        </div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="student" value="student"> 
        <div class="form-inline">
        <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login"> Log In</button>
        </form>
        </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

UPDATE: Thanks guys! It helps me.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection on line 11

Answer (score 1):

Use a session variable for users and one for cashier. So

```
$_SESSION['admin_logged_in']
```

and

```
$_SESSION['cashier_logged_in']
```

or something...

(Also, read this http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the same session variable.
Use different session variables for different logins.